# why the partitioned table is empty?

Tags: google-bigquery, data-partitioning

I tried to partition a table based on a TIMESTAMP column. I ran the following query

`` CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `stackoverflow.questions_2018_partitioned` PARTITION BY DATE(creation_date) AS SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` WHERE creation_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-01'; ``

but the partition table is empty. I copied this query from [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/bigquery-explained-storage-overview).
would you please help me find out my mistake?

Comment: The select statement you have returns valid data ~980k rows.  When you say the table is empty how are you determining that?  Are you running a query, examining the table through the UI?

Comment: yes after creating the table, I ran a simple query to check the records of the table. but it returned no results. the query I ran for examining is copied from the link I mentioned in my question too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the default partition expiration time in your environment is `60 days`. Expiration can be set to `never` with `OPTION (partition_expiration_days = NULL)`. The full command is

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `stackoverflow.questions_2018_partitioned`
PARTITION BY DATE(creation_date)
OPTIONS (partition_expiration_days = NULL) 
AS SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` WHERE creation_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-01';
```

Your personal Google Cloud account with billing-enabled will let you have partitioned tables that don't expire. This will NOT work however, in `qwiklab`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem while populating the partitioned table, and able to find it is due to **default partition expiration** set as **60 days**, and removing the partition expiration helped!!!.

So, remove the partition expiration for your target table `stackoverflow.questions_2018_partitioned`.

Please try below steps for your SQL statement and update your feedback.

```
 1. Create empty partitioned table

      CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `stackoverflow.questions_2018_partitioned` 
      PARTITION BY DATE(creation_date);

 2. Remove partition expiration

      ALTER TABLE `stackoverflow.questions_2018_partitioned`
      SET OPTIONS (
          -- removes partition expiration 
          partition_expiration_days = NULL);

 3. Populate the partitioned table

      INSERT INTO `stackoverflow.questions_2018_partitioned` 
      SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
      WHERE creation_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-01';
```